Mix between injected beans and created beans in spring boot
I have trouble finding a better headline, so forgive me please.
I basically have two classes, a service similar to this:
@Service
public class CharacterService {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate websocket;

    @Autowired
    ArtifactsClient artifactsClient;
    public void bringWoodToBank(String characterName) {
        ....            
        new DepositTask(character, deposit, artifactsClient, websocket, this);
        }
    }

and
public class DepositTask implements Task {

            Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DepositTask.class);

        private final ArtifactsClient artifactsClient;

        private final SimpMessagingTemplate websocket;

        private final CharacterService characterService;

        private de.sveri.artifactsmmo.entities.Character character;

        private Deposit deposit;

        public DepositTask(de.sveri.artifactsmmo.entities.Character character, Deposit deposit,
                ArtifactsClient artifactsClient, SimpMessagingTemplate websocket, CharacterService characterService) {
            this.character = character;
            this.deposit = deposit;
            this.artifactsClient = artifactsClient;
            this.websocket = websocket;
            this.characterService = characterService;
        }
}

As you can see, I am passing in two autowired services into DepositTask. I am unable to make DepositTask itself a @Service, as I need to pass in different parameters, that are available during runtime only.
Is there a spring / boot pattern, that allows me to autowire the services in DepositTask itself or a different one, that enables me to mix and match constructor parameters, so that I can pass in injectable parameters and non injectable parameters?

You can configure your bean however you want by making them different beans. Check out the documentation for @Configuration as it shows examples of how to configure the beans like that. An example would look something like this:
@Configuration
public class YourConfigurationClass {
  @Bean
  DepositTask depositTask1() {
    return new DepositTask(...);
  }

  @Bean
  DepositTask depositTask2() {
    return new DepositTask(...with different values...);
  }
}

Then you can use them by injecting them wherever.
@Component
public class MyUsingClass {
  @Autowired
  private DepositTask depositTask1;

  @Autowired
  private DepositTask depositTask2;

  ...
}


Thanks, I saw @Configure before, but like in your example, I don't understand how to pass in "character" and "deposit" which are runtime generated variables?

Sounds like you are more wanting the factory pattern then.  A factory bean's purpose is to create new instances of objects. I had thought you were more just interested in how to make multiple versions of a bean but if they are runtime specific, the factory pattern is perfect. Check it out here
